# Julia 1.4.2 - Smooth Arrays

Tags: julia, smoothing, moving-average

Is there a function in Julia that is analogous to MATLAB's smooth() function.

MATLAB smooth function:
`z = smooth(y, span, method)` where

- `y` -> input array;
- `span` -> span of moving average;
- `method` -> option between default moving average, lowess, loess etc.

THe result of this operation  `z` is a vector of the same dimension as `y` which is basically a smoothening of the original array `y`.

I can't find a simple function in Julia to do that. TimeSeries.jl has function called `moving()`, but the issue is that we need to transform the input variable first into a `TimeArray` instead of a normal `Array`. The output from the function is a `TimeArray` as well. This is fine, but TimeArray becomes a bit of a problem for some other functions (e.g. those that only allow `Array`, and not `TimeArray`).

Comment: Have a look at DSP.jl, it offers the functions `filt, filtfilt` etc.

Comment: Just a tought. If MATLAB would have been open source one could have just reimplemented and tested it behaves exactly the same..